# In MySql, find strings with a given prefix

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySql, I want to locate records where the string value in one of the columns begins with (or is the same as) a query string. The column is indexed with the appropriate collation order. There is no full-text search index on the column though.

A good solution will:

1. Use the **index** on the column. Solutions that need to iterate over all the records in the table aren't good enough (several million records in the table)
2. Work with strings with **any character values**. Some of the column values contain punctuation characters. The query string might too. Keep this in mind if your solution includes regex characters or similar. The strings are UTF-8 encoded, but if your solution only works with ASCII it could still be useful.

The closest I have at this point is

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName BETWEEN query AND <<query+1>>
```

Where `<<query+1>>` is pre-computed to lexicographically follow `query` in the collation order. For example, if `query` is "o hai" then `<<query+1>>` is "o haj".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Surprisingly, a `LIKE` query will use an index just fine if you're doing a prefix search.

```
SELECT * from TableName Where ColumnName LIKE 'o hai%'
```

will indeed use an index since it does not begin with a wildcard character.

This (and other behavior) is documented in the "How MySQL uses Indexes" doc:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

You will need to escape the '%' character and follow normal quoting rules, but other than that any utf-8 input prefix ought to work and do the job. Run an `EXPLAIN` query to make sure, sometimes other reasons can preclude indexes from working such as needing to do an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to update index cardinalities (though this can take ages and locks your table)

Comment: Perfect -- thanks. EXPLAIN indeed indicates a range query. The MySql docs for LIKE indicate only the following characters need to be escaped: '%', '_': http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like.

Comment: I might mention that in the case index cardinalities do need to be updated, `ANALYZE TABLE` is in theory faster than `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. The table is still locked for write during this time, though. Running ANALYZE TABLE on a table of mine with ~6 million rows took a good hour.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columname LIKE CONCAT(query, '%');
```

Comment: That would work great until `query` has a % or a _ in it. They need to be escaped.

Comment: the '\\' also need be escaped