# SQL query to find records with specific prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm writing SQL queries and getting tripped up by wanting to solve everything with loops instead of set operations. For example, here's two tables (lists, really - one column each); idPrefix is a subset of idFull. I want to select every full ID that has a prefix I'm interested in; that is, every row in idFull which has a corresponding entry in idPrefix.

```
idPrefix.ID     idFull.ID
----------      ---------- 
    12              8
    15              12
    300             12-1-1
                    12-1-2
                    15
                    15-1
                    300
```

Desired result would be everything in idFull except the value 8. Super-easy with a for each loop, but I'm just not conceptualizing it as a set operation. I've tried a few variations on the below; everything seems to return all of one table. I'm not sure if my issue is with how I'm doing joins, or how I'm using LIKE.

```
SELECT f.ID 
FROM idPrefix AS p
JOIN idFull AS f
ON f.ID LIKE (p.ID + '%')
```

Details:

- Values are varchars, prefixes can be any length but do not contain the delimiter '-'.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299996/find-sql-records-containing-similar-strings) seems similar, but more complex; [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011304/in-mysql-find-strings-with-a-given-prefix) only uses one table.
- Answer doesn't need to be fast/optimized/whatever.
- Using SQL Server 2008, but am more interested in conceptual understanding than a flavor-specific query.
- Aaaaand I'm coming back to both real coding & SO after ~3 years, so sorry if I'm rusty on any etiquette.
  Thanks!

Comment: Great question! Welcome back to coding too.

Comment: Have you got any error? What type of idPrefix.ID? You query looks like correct, just replace alias `s` by `f` (you haven't alias `s`).

Comment: I posted an answer that is very similar to what you had in your code example, although I'm not sure where you're pulling the s.UPC from, but your concept is definitely sound.

Comment: Whooops. Was so dang careful proofreading the wording of my question, totally missed that I copied the wrong thing (right query, wrong table/column names). Fixed.

Comment: @Tesherista - And the corrected version doesn't give you the right answer?  Sure seems like it should, although I think you want to `SELECT f.ID` rather than `p.ID`

Comment: @Mihai - LIKE seems to work when I test it with a single value. Not sure how SUBSTRING would be better? Would love to see an example.

Comment: @Danny - no, it doesn't; at first I was getting all of idFull (a very large table), and now I'm getting only the prefixes from idFull (eg: 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 300).

Comment: @Tesherista - were you maybe doing an `OUTER` join first?  That would give you everything, whether it matched a prefix or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the full table to the prefix table with a `LIKE`

```
SELECT idFull.ID
   FROM idFull full
   INNER JOIN idPrefix pre ON full.ID LIKE pre.ID + '%'
```

Comment: Yes! Don't really understand what the difference is, but hopefully I'll mess around and see if I can't figure it out now that the pressure's off. & I'll make sure to come back and upvote this when I have enough rep :)