# SQL Query to pull rows starting with a certain 3 digits

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a numbers column in my sql table and I want to pull all the numbers that start with 3 specific digits; how would I query this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "LIKE" query:

123 is the prefix. I think you have to store the numbers as strings though, just try it out on your data set :-)

```
 SELECT * from TableName Where ColumnName LIKE '123%'
```

See also this Q&A: [In MySql, find strings with a given prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011304/in-mysql-find-strings-with-a-given-prefix)